# how to save a value from cgi.parse_multipart

Tags: python, cgi

here is my code.

```
query = cgi.parse_multipart(rfile, pdict)
upfilecontent = query.get('file')
```

here, I want to save `upfilecontent[0]` to a file in binary mode.

TIA

Comment: 0x330xba is hardly binary data, it's a sort of hex dump.

Comment: Your "binary data", i.e. `'0x330xba.....`, looks like a string representation of 2 or more hexadecimal numbers. Can you be more specific about the possible values and length?

Comment: Your update doesn't really tell us what the value of `upfilecontent[0]` might be.

Comment: That helps -- do you know the exact value of the `'content type'` header?

Answer (score 2):

Since the value is already a `str`, all you have to do is open the file in binary mode and `.write()` it:

```
with file('name.bin', 'wb') as f: # 'w' for writing, 'b' for binary
    f.write(d['key_1'])
```

If you wanted to re-interpret the text as actually being some kind of hex dump, or something else, then you'll have to be more specific.

Comment: Should it not be 'with open' ? If not, what is the difference of both forms? Cheers!

Comment: @Morlock: Incompatibility with py3

Comment: They are effectively equivalent. The type is called `file`, so `file()` is calling the constructor, whereas `open` is a factory function that creates a `file` instance. The community decided years ago that writing `open()` is idiomatic and preferred, and that `file` should only be used for type-testing (which is rare). In Python 3.0, `file` is gone; the type is now io.stream() or something like that, which arguably makes more sense, but I would still rather write io.stream() than open(). I consider it far more idiomatic to create the thing by calling the constructor. I'm a heretic :)

Comment: An idiomatic `open()` would work in both Python 2.x and 3.x, and as others have mentioned `file` is gone in v3. So while I understand your rationale, unless it absolutely required -- such as when deriving a new subclass -- it might be better if you didn't foist your own idiosyncrasy on others.

Answer (score 0):

```
def writeBinaryData(binaryData):
    f = open("data.bin", "wb")
    f.write(binaryData)
```

The "b" in the mode string for a file specifies that you want to read/write binary data.

However, you're example looks like you'll key_1's value is a hexadecimal string "0x330xba" that you'll need to convert to binary first.

Answer (score 0):

From the latest information in you question it sounds like you want to write a **byte** stream to a file in binary. As earlier answers have shown, this is easy, just make sure to first open the file in binary mode (the trailing 'b' in the second argument to open).

```
f = open("output_file_name", "wb")
f.write(upfilecontent[0])
f.close()
```

If that doesn't work, try printing out `repr(upfilecontent[0][:64])`. If the result looks like a series of hex digits without leading `0x`'s, then you'll need to decode it into byte values before writing.